# SQL Table Mapping

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with over 100k six digit CIP codes and concerned titles:

SixDigitCIPTable:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| SixDigitCIPCode |               SixDigitCIPTitle                |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|         01.0000 | Agriculture, General                          |
|         01.0102 | Agribusiness/Agricultural Business Operations |
|         01.0201 | Agricultural Mechanization, General           |
|         03.0501 | Forestry, General                             |
|         05.0112 | South Asian Studies                           |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I need to map this with two digit and four digit CIP code and title.
Four digit CIP table is like,

FourDigitCIPTable:

```
+------------------+--------------------------------------+
| FourDigitCIPCode |          FourDigitCIPTitle           |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+
|            01.00 | Agriculture, General                 |
|            01.01 | Agricultural Business and Management |
|            01.02 | Agricultural Mechanization           |
|            03.05 | Forestry                             |
|            05.01 | Area Studies                         |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

TwoDigitCIPTable:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| TwoDigitCIPCode |                     TwoDigitCIPTitle                      |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|              01 | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences |
|              01 | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences |
|              01 | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences |
|              03 | Natural Resources And Conservation                        |
|              05 | Area, Ethnic, Cultural, Gender, And Group Studies         |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have loaded each two, four and six-digit CIP lookup value in three different SQL tables.
I need to insert two digit and four digit CIP details in the SixDigitCIPTable with corresponding values.

For example,

The First record of SixDigitCIPTable is,

```
01.0000 | Agriculture, General
```

so the two digit code will be 01, while mapping this two digit code in TwoDigitCIPTable the record to map is,

```
01  | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences
```

and four digit code will be 01.00, while mapping this four digit code in FourDigitCIPTable the record to map is,

```
01.00   | Agriculture, General
```

so after inserting both two and four digit code in SixDigitCIPTable the first record should be like,

```
01  | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences | 01.00 | Agriculture, General |    01.0000 | Agriculture, General
```

Finally SixDigitCIPTable should be like,

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
| TwoDigitCIPCode |                     TwoDigitCIPTitle                      | FourDigitCIPCode |          FourDigitCIPTitle           | SixDigitCIPCode |          SixDigitCIPTitle           |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
|              01 | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences |            01.00 | Agriculture, General                 |         01.0000 | Agriculture, General                |
|              01 | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences |            01.01 | Agricultural Business and Management |                 |                                     |
|         01.0102 | Agribusiness/Agricultural Business Operations             |                  |                                      |                 |                                     |
|              01 | Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, And Related Sciences |            01.02 | Agricultural Mechanization           |         01.0201 | Agricultural Mechanization, General |
|              03 | Natural Resources And Conservation                        |            03.05 | Forestry                             |          3.0501 | Forestry, General                   |
|              05 | Area, Ethnic, Cultural, Gender, And Group Studies         |            05.01 | Area Studies                         |         05.0112 | South Asian Studies                 |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Is there any possibilities to do like this in SQL?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You have a perfectly fine table structure (apart from maybe splitting up your primary keys into composite keys to make joins easier and faster), and you want to denormalize it? Use `join` to get your endresult. Do not change your tables to get that endresult.

Comment: `join` do not work i guess. Because each table has different number records and not in ascending order. For sample I have provided five records. So we cannot directly join the tables.

Comment: Of course you can use joins, this is what a relational database is made for (otherwise you don't need a database). Try `select * from TwoDigitCIP two join FourDigitCIP four on two.TwoDigitCIPCode = left(four.FourDigitCIPCode,2) join SixDigitCIP six on four.FourDigitCIPCode = left(six.SixDigitCIPCode,5)`. Splitting your codes in 1, 2 and 3 columns would allow nicer joins and foreign keys (e.g., check if `01` exists in table two before you add `01.00` into table four), but this will work fine the way it is. I repeat: Please do not put all your data into one giant table.